# Database [default] Driver not found - MySQL in Playframework 1.4.x

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-1.x

Can't seem to connect to connect to a locally hosted MySQL 5 database using the jdbc driver.

My application is simply the one created by running `play new` on 1.4.x and I added the following to my `application.conf`

```
 db.default.url="mysql://localhost:3306/test"
 db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 db.default.user="jsmit"
 db.default.password="pass123"
```

When I try to hit `localhost:9000`, I get the following error:

```
 A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database[default], Database [default] Driver not found ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

As I understand, this driver should be packaged in `mysql-java-connector` shipped under `framework/lib`. I couldn't find anyone running into this issue on play 1.X.

Comment: Check your build.sbt, you should have mysql-java-connector in libraryDependencies   like this  `libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.47"` in correct version (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html)

Comment: @Tijkijiki Play 1.x does not use sbt

Comment: You are right, sry. What about dependencies.yml? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/dependency

Comment: @Tijkijiki for reasons that I fail to understand, the real issue is that `db.default.url` needs to be supplied as a environment variable. This one really came out of left field :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like `db.default.url` needs to be loaded as an environment variable. In the example above, add the following in your shell's profile:

```
export DB_URL="mysql://localhost:3306/test"
```

and make your `application.conf` the following:

```
db.default.url=${DB_URL}
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user="jsmith"
db.default.password="pass123"
```